# What is the domain and the range of $h(x,y)=\ln(1 + \exp(-(x+1)(y-1))$ and $h(x,y)=\exp((y-x)^2+2(2-x)^2)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

i. $h(x,y)=\ln(1 + \exp(-(x+1)(y-1))$

idea: due to the $\ln$

$(1 + \exp(-(x+1)(y-1))> 0$

due to the $\exp$

$-(x+1)(y-1)>0$ at this point I don't know how to continue

ii. $h(x,y)=\exp((y-x)^2+2(2-x)^2)$

due to the $\exp$
$((y-x)^2 +2(2-x)^2) >0$

Comment: Since $e^{\gamma}>0$ for all $\gamma$, $1+e^{\gamma}>0$ is always true hence the domain should be $\mathbb{R}^2$ for i and ii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For i):

Domain: Because of the $\ln$ you need that $1+\exp(-(x+1)(y-1))>0$ but this is always the case.

Range: For $x=-y$ you get $h(-y,y)=\ln(1+\exp((y-1)^2))>\ln(\exp((y-1)^2))=(y-1)^2$, hence the function is unbounded. Furthermore you can show that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} h(x,x)=\ln(1+0).$$
The range is $(0,\infty)$.

For ii)
Domain: $\mathbb{R}^2$ as well.

Range: You can easily check that $h(x,x)$ is unbounded. Furthermore $h(2,2)=1$, hence the range is $\left[1,\infty\right)$.